# Error: Unknown named parameter $$dbi in Phpmyadmin 5.2.1

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have update my `phpmyadmin` up to 5.2.1 over SSH. The update returns no errors and was ended successfully. I have tried to Login and next to the Login shows me only the error: `Error: Unknown named parameter $$dbi`. I have found no solution for this Problem and hope I can find help.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, provide as much code, configuration or whatever details as possible. Nobody is obligated to guess what's going on!

Answer (score 5):

**Edit the file**

php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php

**Change this line**

$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs($arguments);

**To look as follows:**

$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs(array_values($arguments));

Comment: The full path for me was `/usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after ugrading Ubuntu 18 to 20. couldn't figure out what was wrong. Had to download a fresh copy of phpmyadmin and manually installed and it's now working.

I downloaded the lastest phpmyadmin from here
wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem re-installing phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 20.04 via apt.
Manual install worked for me too, guided by instructions at https://tecadmin.net/install-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-20-04/
Had to adjust for .conf file under /etc/apache2 (not apache)
Also adjusted ownership to (myid):www-data as I run Apache as my own ID, not www-data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).